# How to leave data type undetermined in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to write a method that gets the highest value out of any HashMap, regardless of what data type the key is.

For example:

```
public static int getMax(HashMap<String, Integer> map){

    int maxValue = 0;
    for (String key : map.keySet()){
        int value = map.get(key);
        if (value > maxValue){
            maxValue = value;
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

However, I thought it would be nice if I could write this in such a way that the key data type didn't matter so long as the value data type is an integer. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Set the Key to be of the Object class. It will encompass all possible objects.

Comment: Use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: @MichaelBianconi unfortunately, I tried this and it did not work. When I try passing a HashMap with keys that are strings to my getMax function, I receive `incompatible types: HashMap<String, Integer> cannot be converted to HashMap<Object, Integer>`

Comment: @rocksNwaves: Don't assume that 0 is maximum. If all values in the map are negative, then also the maximum will be negative, where as your approach will return max = 0, which will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [unbounded wildcard (`?`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) and switch to `Object` in your loop:

```
public static int getMax(HashMap<?, Integer> map) {

    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Object key : map.keySet()){
        int value = map.get(key);
        if (value > maxValue){
            maxValue = value;
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

Note that you should also change your initial `maxValue` from `0` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. And as a general (not for learning purposes) approach I would advise a [solution using streams as provided by mentallurg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59778791/4616087).

Comment: Setting maxValue to 0 is not correct. If values in the map are all in the range (-500, -100), your approach will give max = 0, where as max can be actually -100.

Comment: I left the rest of OP's method unchanged. But you are correct, I'll change it.

Comment: @mentallurg I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted. Marvin used `int maxValue = 0` because I did in my question. He was adapting my code, and shouldn't be downvoted for MY bad code. You should make that comment on my question rather than his answer.

Comment: @rocksNwaves Still good to point it out, I'm not blaming mentallurg for that. And the solution using streams is IMHO clearly preferrable in production code.

Comment: @Marvin I agree, I have a lot to learn and streams recently caught my attention in the docs. However, I didn't like the unnecessary downvote. Your answer spoke very well to my current level of knowledge, while his shows where I have room to grow and learn.

Answer (score 2):

You can use streams:

```
Optional<Integer> max = map.values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

You want *that the key data type didn't matter*. This solution provides exactly that.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't learned about Streams yet. I just read about them in the docs last week, but I think that's jumping way ahead of where I am in my online classes now. I also haven't learned about Comparator yet, although I have also come across it in the docs. I'm looking for a solution that works for my current level of knowledge. I'm sure this answer will help someone who is more advanced than me.

Comment: Even without streams you can take *map.values()* and iterate in a loop, if this it easier to you.